# issue with siteminder agent configuration with httpd compiled version on RHEL

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, make

I have built httpd using source code on RHEL 7.6. I have installed and configured siteminder on the server. I am getting following error when I start my httpd

> httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot
>   load /opt/CA/webagent/bin/libmod_sm24.so into server: libsmerrlog.so:
>   cannot open shared object #file: No such file or directory [Inferior 1
>   (process 28063) exited with code 01]

I found this [solution](https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=786989), but I cant find  /etc/sysconfig/httpd for the changing the configuration.

I know this directory gets generated when we intall httpd rpm package from RHEL and I dont want to do that as its not compatible with what I am doing. Any ideas on how to solve the issue?
Thanks
Nate

Answer (score 0):

I have added the paths in envvars in the bin directory

```
export NETE_WA_ROOT=/opt/CA/webagent
export NETE_WA_PATH=/opt/CA/webagent/bin
export CAPKIHOME=/opt/CA/webagent/CAPKI
```

that resolved the issue.